# How to flatten a hierarchy with Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, hierarchical-data

I have a 6 level deep Parent / child hierarchy df which is as follows

```
Hierarchy Name,Hierarchy Node ID,Hierarchy Level,Hierarchy Node Desc,Node Higher

0,L1,1,1,Top level,#
1,L110,1072,2,Level 2,1
2,L1100,992,3,Level 3 A,1072
3,L1101,994,3,Level 3 B,1072
4,L1102,997,3,Level 3 C,1072
5,L1103,1013,4,Level 4 1,992
6,L1104,1014,5,Level 5 A,1013
```

I want to flatten this into the following dataframe for all the paths from the bottom level to the top e.g.

```
NodeID, NodeDesc, Lvl1, lvl1desc, lvl2, lvl2desc, ...lvl5, lvl5desc

1,Top Level, 1072, Level 2, 992, Level 3 A, 1013, Level 4 1, 1014, Level 5 A
```

My method which works is as follows,

Step 1 add a column of parent and child

```
df2['Dictionery'] = list(zip(df2['Hierarchy Node ID'], df2['Node ID of the 
Highe']))
ancestry = df2['Dictionery']
```

step 2 get the path of all relationships, I found this code online for printing out the full path of a parent /child tree

```
l=[]
parents = set()
children = {}
for c,p,cd in ancestry:
    parents.add(p)
    children[c] = p
# recursively determine parents until child has no parent
def ancestors(p):
    return (ancestors(children[p]) if p in children else []) + [p]

# for each child that has no children print the geneology
for k in (set(children.keys()) - parents):
   l.append('/'.join(ancestors(k)))
```

Add the path to a dataframe

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(l, columns = ['Path'])
```

Split the path column into each of the level node ids

```
new = df3["Path"].str.split("/", expand = True) 
df3["Level1"]= new[0] 
df3["Level2"]= new[1]
df3["Level3"]= new[2] 
df3["Level4"]= new[3] 
df3["Level5"]= new[4] 
df3["Level6"]= new[5] 
df3["Level7"]= new[6]
df3.fillna(value=0, inplace=True)
```

Which gives the following df3

```
path,  Level1,  Level2 , Level3, Level4, Level5, Level 6

0   #/1/1071/1249/1504/1505/1546, #, 1, 1071 , 1249, 1504, 1505 , 1546

1   #/1/1071/1249/1250/1269/1275, #, 1, 1071, 1249, 1250, 1269, 1275
```

I then created a dictionary from original df to map the node id and description e.g.

```
{'Hierarchy Node Desc': {0: '0.0',
  1: 'Top Level',
  1072: 'Level 2',
  992: 'Level 3 A',
  994: 'Level 3 B',
  997: 'Level 3 C',
  1013: 'Level 4 1',
...}}
```

I then map new columns for the description in  df3 for each Level using the dictionary

e.g.

```
df['Level2desc'] = df['Level2'].map(dict)
```

This gives me the flat hierarchy I am after but it just seems a lot of work to get to it and I expect there is a much simpler / more efficient way to do it.

Any advice to do this in simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first identify all terminal items, meaning items with no child. Then for every terminal item, I would build the list of its parents. Code could be:

```
# find max hierarchy level
mx = df['Hierarchy Level'].max()

# identify terminal items
last = df[~df['Hierarchy Node ID'].isin(pd.to_numeric(df['Node Higher'],
                                                      errors='coerce'))]

# build a list for any terminal items with all of its parents
data = []
for _, row in last.iterrows():
    # initialize row
    hrow= {'lvl'+str(i+1)+ext: '' for i in range(mx) for ext in ['', 'desc']}
    # populate lvli and lvlidesc for the item and its parents
    for lvl in range(row['Hierarchy Level'], 0, -1):
        hrow['lvl'+str(lvl)] = row['Hierarchy Node ID']
        hrow['lvl'+str(lvl) + 'desc'] = row['Hierarchy Node Desc']
        # process parent until top level
        try:
            row = df[df['Hierarchy Node ID']==int(row['Node Higher'])].iloc[0]
        except:
            break
    data.append(hrow)

# build the resulting dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

With your sample data I get:

```
   lvl1   lvl1desc  lvl2 lvl2desc  lvl3   lvl3desc  lvl4   lvl4desc  lvl5   lvl5desc
0     1  Top level  1072  Level 2   994  Level 3 B                                  
1     1  Top level  1072  Level 2   997  Level 3 C                                  
2     1  Top level  1072  Level 2   992  Level 3 A  1013  Level 4 1  1014  Level 5 A
```

If you only want the last line, it is enough to change `last` to:

```
last = df[df['Hierarchy Level']==mx]
```

Comment: Thank you, it works on the sample data above, but in the larger data set that I have it doesnt.

Comment: Not sure why this is the case as the structure is the same, it is just that there is a lot more data for example last = df[df['Hierarchy Level']==mx] identifies 1810 rows at level 6. The output dataframe just has entries for lvl6, lvl6 desc with the rest of the path empty. But i iwill take a look at the code and see where i get too. thank you

Comment: @Ian What happens in the larger dataframe? Any exception with a stacktrace?

Comment: Serge, I figured it out, the Hierarchy Node ID in my large dataset was loaded in as Object data type, changed it to int and worked perfectly.